# design wavy background in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react native and starting to learn UI design.

I am trying to create wavy background (as in the bottom portion of first card or pink section of the third card) shown in the below image. I searched in multiple react native packages, but haven't found something that implements this.

My question is that

1. if this type of background design is possible to implement by using some react native packages or the background image has to be designed like 
   this in some image editing application (like adobe photoshop)?
2. if this is possible by some react native packages, then any library recommendation or working code will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Image Source: Google

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [package](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) and draw your wavy background with SVG, or set uri of your SVG.

Following code is sample wavy background in React Native

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

export const WavyBackground = () => (
  <View>
    <SvgUri
      width="200"
      height="200"
      source={{uri:'custom wavy svg url here'}}
    />
  </View>
);
```